# Creating a URL handler, but still getting 404. Is my regular expression wrong?

Tags: python, regex, google-app-engine, webapp2

I am making a RequestHandler to handle tags on an app engine application. The URL is of the format

```
www.example.com/tags/tag=sometag
```

and my URL handler is as follows

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(['/tags/"[a-zA-Z0-9=+]*$"', TagsHandler], debug=True)
```

I wrote that regular expression to accept any alphanumeric value including + and =. Am I right in thinking that this is the source of my problem ?

This is so that I can get the parameter `tag` from the url by using `request.get` and then displaying all posts tagged with that particular tag.

## Edit

The question was answered:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication['tags/[a-zA-Z0-9+=]*$', TagsHandler],  debug=True)
```

The quotes are not a part of the regular expression

Comment: there is no need to edit your questions with the answer.. I think it is pretty clear from the actual answer.. and since there is a checkmark that means that it is solved..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you using quotes here?

```
'/tags/"[a-zA-Z0-9=+]*$"'
       ^               ^
```

Can you just remove them?

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I did not realize that the quotes weren't a part of the regex.